# What about a feature where the asker can transfer a comment to an answer?

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers

I've noticed a trend where people like to answer the question in the comments section. This means as the asker I have to ask them to make an answer for me to accept it, which people sometimes don't want to do even though they are the earliest and most helpful answer. This, of course, breaks the question-answer format of SO.

Can we make a feature where we can make a comment into an answer as the asker? Are there alternate solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't get the poster of the comment to eventually respond to your requests to make it an answer, post the answer yourself, make it Community Wiki, and mark it as the correct answer when the system allows you to.